# Hide element on certrain time YouTube API

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, youtube, timestamp

I am using the YouTube API and managed to trigger an event on a certain time. But now I want to hide the triggered event a couple of seconds later. So for example a div is shown at 4 seconds en I want to hide it at 6 seconds.
But I cannot make it work. I can get the div show up at 4sec and hide at 6sec but then the timer keeps tracking time even when the video is paused. So I am doing something wrong.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkK7/291/) to the code (script is not my own, I just found it on the web and changed it a bit)

HTML:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="showTest">Test</div>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('showTest').style.display = 'none';

(function() {
  var showText1 = 4, // Stop play at time in seconds
  showTextTimer;   // Reference to settimeout call

  // This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  // after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
      "height": "315",
      "width": "560",
      "videoId": "L6cVcbkx8l8",
      "events": {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady,
      "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
   }
});
}

// The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
// This automatically starts the video playback when the player is loaded.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}
// The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  var time, rate, remainingTime;
  clearTimeout(showTextTimer);
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
  time = player.getCurrentTime();
  // Add .4 of a second to the time in case it's close to the current time
  // (The API kept returning ~9.7 when hitting play after stopping at 10s)
  if (time + .4 < showText1) {
    rate = player.getPlaybackRate();
    remainingTime = (showText1 - time) / rate;
    showTextTimer = setTimeout(showTxt, remainingTime * 1000);
  }   
}
}
function showTxt() {
document.getElementById('showTest').style.display = 'block';
}
})();
```

So to sum up, I want to show a div at 4sec and hide it at 6sec. But when the video is paused the timer needs to be cleared so the events will not be triggered.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out on my own. Maybe it can help someone else out.

Within an else every timer needs to be cleared.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkK7/292/).

```
document.getElementById('showTest').style.display = 'none';

(function() {
var showText1 = 4, // Stop play at time in seconds
    showTextTimer;   // Reference to settimeout call
var hideText1 = 6, // Stop play at time in seconds
    hideTextTimer;   // Reference to settimeout call    

// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
// after the API code downloads.
var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    "height": "315",
    "width": "560",
    "videoId": "L6cVcbkx8l8",
    "events": {
    "onReady": onPlayerReady,
    "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
  }
});
}

// The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
// This automatically starts the video playback when the player is loaded.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.playVideo();
}

// The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  var time, rate, remainingTime, remainingTime2;
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    time = player.getCurrentTime();
    rate = player.getPlaybackRate();  
    // Add .4 of a second to the time in case it's close to the current time
    // (The API kept returning ~9.7 when hitting play after stopping at 10s)
    if (time + .4 < showText1) {
      remainingTime = (showText1 - time) / rate;
      showTextTimer = setTimeout(showTxt, remainingTime * 1000);
    }
    if (time + .4 < hideText1) {
      remainingTime2 = (hideText1 - time) / rate;
      hideTextTimer = setTimeout(hideTxt, remainingTime2 * 1000);
    }          
  }
  else {
        clearTimeout(showTextTimer);
        clearTimeout(hideTextTimer);
  }
}
function showTxt() {
  document.getElementById('showTest').style.display = 'block';
}
function hideTxt() {
  document.getElementById('showTest').style.display = 'none';
}    
})();
```